# R different trendline for raw vs summary dataframe plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, mixed-models

I am having trouble creating a summary figure with means and 95% CI for % cover of algae vs recruitment of corals.

#### Database

```
data <- structure(list(`Module #` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("111", "112", "113", "114", 
"115", "116", "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216"), class = "factor"), 
    TimeStep = structure(c(1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 
    6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 
    10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
    2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 
    6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 
    10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
    "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "factor"), 
    Site_long = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki"), class = "factor"), 
    Shelter = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Low", "High"), class = c("ordered", 
    "factor")), Year = c(17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 17, 17, 18, 
    18, 19, 19, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 
    17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 17, 17, 18, 
    18, 19, 19, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 
    17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 17, 17, 18, 
    18, 19, 19), Season = c("summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
    "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
    "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
    "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
    "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
    "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
    "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
    "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
    "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
    "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
    "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall"), `Taxonomic Code` = c("PR", 
    "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
    "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
    "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
    "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
    "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
    "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
    "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
    "PR"), Settlement_Area_final = c(2, 2, 1.75902336, 2, 2, 
    1.426963917, 2, 2, 2, 1.75902336, 1.75902336, 1.637579622, 
    1.51804672, 1.75902336, 1.75902336, 2, 1.510456486, 2, 1.51804672, 
    1.51804672, 2, 1.75902336, 1.510456486, 1.698301491, 1.75902336, 
    1.51804672, 1.75902336, 1.75902336, 1.51804672, 1.75902336, 
    2, 2, 2, 1.51804672, 1.667940557, 1.404193216, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 1.46300425, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1.75902336, 1.75902336, 
    1.75902336, 1.75902336, 1.614808922, 2, 1.75902336, 1.75902336, 
    2, 0.9487792, 1.37951168, 1.409872614, 1.75902336, 1.51804672, 
    1.75902336, 1.75902336, 1.743842893, 1.607218688, 1.75902336, 
    1.51804672, 1.366242048, 1.290339712, 1.206847142, 1.561677286
    ), recruits_new = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 4, 
    3, 1, 0, 5, 0, 6, 5, 0, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 
    2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 4, 1, 1, 4, 8, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 8, 5, 4, 
    2, 1), coral_count_new = c(2, 2, 7, 7, 9, 13, 0, 0, 2, 3, 
    6, 8, 5, 9, 14, 16, 23, 22, 6, 13, 12, 5, 17, 14, 2, 1, 13, 
    21, 18, 18, 0, 1, 5, 9, 10, 8, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 10, 13, 12, 11, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 7, 4, 10, 14, 
    20, 29, 31, 4, 13, 27, 26, 15, 10), percent_recruits = c(0, 
    0, 0.142857142857143, 0, 0, 0.307692307692308, NaN, NaN, 
    0, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.125, 0.8, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.0714285714285714, 0, 0.217391304347826, 0, 1, 0.384615384615385, 
    0, 0.2, 0.235294117647059, 0.142857142857143, 1, 4, 0.153846153846154, 
    0.238095238095238, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
    NaN, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.1, 0.375, NaN, NaN, 0, NaN, 
    0, 0.333333333333333, NaN, NaN, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.1, 
    0.153846153846154, 0.0833333333333333, 0, 1, 0.5, 0, 1.33333333333333, 
    0.25, 0.142857142857143, 1, 0.8, 0.142857142857143, 0.15, 
    0.0689655172413793, 0.032258064516129, 1, 0.615384615384615, 
    0.185185185185185, 0.153846153846154, 0.133333333333333, 
    0.1), recruits_per_meter_squared = c(0, 0, 0.56849728249203, 
    0, 0, 2.80315427205017, 0, 0, 0, 0.56849728249203, 1.13699456498406, 
    0.610657330224154, 2.63496501609647, 1.70549184747609, 0.56849728249203, 
    0, 3.31025755878677, 0, 3.95244752414471, 3.29370627012059, 
    0, 0.56849728249203, 2.64820604702941, 1.177647202572, 1.13699456498406, 
    2.63496501609647, 1.13699456498406, 2.84248641246015, 1.31748250804824, 
    0.56849728249203, 0, 0, 0, 1.97622376207236, 0.599541749736349, 
    2.1364581211593, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.683525013683316, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.56849728249203, 1.13699456498406, 0.56849728249203, 
    1.13699456498406, 0.619268314892305, 0, 1.13699456498406, 
    1.13699456498406, 0, 4.21594402575436, 0.724894188645072, 
    0.709283938187057, 2.27398912996812, 5.26993003219295, 1.13699456498406, 
    1.70549184747609, 1.14689230780379, 0.622192864895309, 2.27398912996812, 
    5.26993003219295, 3.65967363346732, 3.09995884246644, 1.65721070249674, 
    0.640337161182224), Date_new.x = structure(c(17301, 17387, 
    17684, 17780, 18046, 18144, 17306, 17389, 17682, 17773, 18047, 
    18140, 17304, 17390, 17675, 17782, 18039, 18139, 17299, 17389, 
    17682, 17780, 18039, 18139, 17299, 17388, 17677, 17773, 18048, 
    18140, 17292, 17387, 17675, 17782, 18046, 18144, 17288, 17386, 
    17687, 17783, 18037, 18135, 17288, 17386, 17687, 17783, 18037, 
    18135, 17288, 17386, 17687, 17783, 18044, 18142, 17288, 17386, 
    17687, 17783, 18044, 18135, 17288, 17386, 17680, 17783, 18037, 
    18142, 17288, 17386, 17683.5, 17783, 18044, 18135), class = "Date"), 
    Date.x = structure(c(17301, 17387, 17684, 17780, 18046, 18144, 
    17306, 17389, 17682, 17773, 18047, 18140, 17304, 17390, 17675, 
    17782, 18039, 18139, 17299, 17389, 17682, 17780, 18039, 18139, 
    17299, 17388, 17677, 17773, 18048, 18140, 17292, 17387, 17675, 
    17782, 18046, 18144, 17288, 17386, 17687, 17783, 18037, 18135, 
    17288, 17386, 17687, 17783, 18037, 18135, 17288, 17386, 17687, 
    17783, 18044, 18142, 17288, 17386, 17687, 17783, 18044, 18135, 
    17288, 17386, 17680, 17783, 18037, 18142, 17288, 17386, 17683.5, 
    17783, 18044, 18135), class = "Date"), Site = c("WAI", "WAI", 
    "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", 
    "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", 
    "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", 
    "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "HAN", "HAN", 
    "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", 
    "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", 
    "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", 
    "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN", "HAN"), Treatment = c("OPE", 
    "OPE", "OPE", "OPE", "OPE", "OPE", "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", 
    "CLO", "CLO", "OPE", "OPE", "OPE", "OPE", "OPE", "OPE", "CLO", 
    "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", "OPE", "OPE", "OPE", "OPE", 
    "OPE", "OPE", "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", "OPE", 
    "OPE", "OPE", "OPE", "OPE", "OPE", "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", 
    "CLO", "CLO", "OPE", "OPE", "OPE", "OPE", "OPE", "OPE", "CLO", 
    "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", "OPE", "OPE", "OPE", "OPE", 
    "OPE", "OPE", "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", "CLO", "CLO"), 
    Module = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), combined_cover = c(0.93, 0.97, 0.9, 
    0.92, 0.96, 0.909090909090909, 0.91, 0.87, 0.979381443298969, 
    0.93, 0.97, 0.9, 0.8, 0.9, 0.920792079207921, 0.9, 0.88, 
    0.81, 0.81, 0.71, 0.910112359550562, 0.92, 0.92, 0.94, 0.97, 
    0.94, 0.96, 0.92, 0.86, 0.89, 0.89, 0.82, 0.92, 0.868686868686869, 
    0.89, 0.89, 0.878787878787879, 0.752577319587629, 0.94, 0.98, 
    0.89, 0.98, 0.84, 0.88, 0.941176470588235, 0.939393939393939, 
    0.91, 0.98019801980198, 0.636363636363636, 0.878787878787879, 
    0.838383838383838, 0.74, 0.83, 0.94, 0.78, 0.808080808080808, 
    0.919191919191919, 0.918367346938776, 0.9, 0.93, 0.45, 0.61, 
    0.87, 0.8, 0.910891089108911, 0.9, 0.87, 0.92, 0.99, 0.929292929292929, 
    0.93, 0.96), Date_new.y = structure(c(17279, 17404, 17689, 
    17775, 18032, 18165, 17279, 17404, 17689, 17775, 18032, 18165, 
    17279, 17404, 17689, 17775, 18032, 18165, 17279, 17404, 17689, 
    17775, 18032, 18165, 17279, 17404, 17689, 17775, 18032, 18165, 
    17279, 17404, 17689, 17775, 18032, 18165, 17267, 17414, 17694, 
    17771, 18023, 18163, 17267, 17414, 17694, 17771, 18023, 18163, 
    17267, 17414, 17694, 17771, 18023, 18163, 17267, 17414, 17694, 
    17771, 18023, 18163, 17267, 17414, 17694, 17771, 18023, 18163, 
    17267, 17414, 17694, 17771, 18023, 18163), class = "Date"), 
    Date.y = structure(c(17279, 17404, 17689, 17775, 18032, 18165, 
    17279, 17404, 17689, 17775, 18032, 18165, 17279, 17404, 17689, 
    17775, 18032, 18165, 17279, 17404, 17689, 17775, 18032, 18165, 
    17279, 17404, 17689, 17775, 18032, 18165, 17279, 17404, 17689, 
    17775, 18032, 18165, 17267, 17414, 17694, 17771, 18023, 18163, 
    17267, 17414, 17694, 17771, 18023, 18163, 17267, 17414, 17694, 
    17771, 18023, 18163, 17267, 17414, 17694, 17771, 18023, 18163, 
    17267, 17414, 17694, 17771, 18023, 18163, 17267, 17414, 17694, 
    17771, 18023, 18163), class = "Date"), Treatment_long = c("Open", 
    "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Closed", "Closed", 
    "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
    "Open", "Open", "Open", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
    "Closed", "Closed", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
    "Open", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", 
    "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
    "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Closed", 
    "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Open", 
    "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Open", "Closed", "Closed", 
    "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed"), combined_cover_trans = c(0.0676586484738147, 
    0.0295588022415444, 0.0953101798043249, 0.0769610411361284, 
    0.0392207131532813, 0.0870113769896297, 0.0861776962410522, 
    0.122217632724249, 0.020408871631207, 0.0676586484738149, 
    0.0295588022415444, 0.0953101798043249, 0.182321556793955, 
    0.0953101798043249, 0.0762273653878843, 0.0953101798043249, 
    0.113328685307003, 0.173953307123438, 0.173953307123438, 
    0.254642218373581, 0.086074608771243, 0.0769610411361284, 
    0.0769610411361284, 0.0582689081239758, 0.0295588022415444, 
    0.0582689081239758, 0.0392207131532813, 0.0769610411361284, 
    0.131028262406404, 0.104360015324243, 0.104360015324243, 
    0.165514438477574, 0.0769610411361284, 0.123379021160505, 
    0.104360015324243, 0.104360015324243, 0.114410351177744, 
    0.221079567093358, 0.0582689081239758, 0.0198026272961797, 
    0.104360015324243, 0.0198026272961797, 0.148420005118273, 
    0.113328685307003, 0.0571584138399486, 0.0588405000229334, 
    0.0861776962410524, 0.0196084713883763, 0.31015492830384, 
    0.114410351177744, 0.14981227822866, 0.231111720963387, 0.157003748809665, 
    0.0582689081239758, 0.198850858745165, 0.175564774331075, 
    0.0777089843273163, 0.0784716154414953, 0.0953101798043249, 
    0.0676586484738147, 0.438254930931155, 0.3293037471426, 0.122217632724249, 
    0.182321556793955, 0.0853598489511568, 0.0953101798043249, 
    0.122217632724249, 0.0769610411361284, 0.00995033085316809, 
    0.0683192439774772, 0.0676586484738149, 0.0392207131532813
    ), Date = structure(c(17279, 17404, 17689, 17775, 18032, 
    18165, 17279, 17404, 17689, 17775, 18032, 18165, 17279, 17404, 
    17689, 17775, 18032, 18165, 17279, 17404, 17689, 17775, 18032, 
    18165, 17279, 17404, 17689, 17775, 18032, 18165, 17279, 17404, 
    17689, 17775, 18032, 18165, 17267, 17414, 17694, 17771, 18023, 
    18163, 17267, 17414, 17694, 17771, 18023, 18163, 17267, 17414, 
    17694, 17771, 18023, 18163, 17267, 17414, 17694, 17771, 18023, 
    18163, 17267, 17414, 17694, 17771, 18023, 18163, 17267, 17414, 
    17694, 17771, 18023, 18163), class = "Date"), recruits_per_meter_squared_trans = c(0, 
    0, 0.450118016094994, 0, 0, 1.33583079400559, 0, 0, 0, 0.450118016094994, 
    0.759400433041338, 0.476642375315249, 1.29059948675663, 0.995283724781047, 
    0.450118016094994, 0, 1.4609976607494, 0, 1.59988190370298, 
    1.45715029239415, 0, 0.450118016094994, 1.29423555280711, 
    0.778245029100044, 0.759400433041338, 1.29059948675663, 0.759400433041338, 
    1.34611966030469, 0.840481470661638, 0.450118016094994, 0, 
    0, 0, 1.0906553030127, 0.469717181808803, 1.1430941763722, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.520889817651359, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.450118016094994, 
    0.759400433041338, 0.450118016094994, 0.759400433041338, 
    0.481974389742448, 0, 0.759400433041338, 0.759400433041338, 
    0, 1.65172009330802, 0.545165708686053, 0.536074533216259, 
    1.18600915883595, 1.83576519544269, 0.759400433041338, 0.995283724781047, 
    0.764021358255194, 0.483778854231975, 1.18600915883595, 1.83576519544269, 
    1.53894540994831, 1.41097693523706, 0.977276964535573, 0.494901806792905
    )), row.names = c(NA, -72L), groups = structure(list(`Module #` = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("111", 
"112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "211", "212", "213", "214", 
"215", "216"), class = "factor"), TimeStep = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 
9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 
9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "factor"), 
    Site_long = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki"), class = "factor"), 
    Shelter = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Low", "High"), class = c("ordered", 
    "factor")), Year = c(17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 17, 17, 18, 
    18, 19, 19, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 
    17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 17, 17, 18, 
    18, 19, 19, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 
    17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 17, 17, 18, 
    18, 19, 19), Season = c("summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
    "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
    "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
    "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
    "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
    "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
    "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
    "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
    "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
    "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
    "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall"), .rows = structure(list(
        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
        14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
        25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
        36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 
        47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
        58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 
        69L, 70L, 71L, 72L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 72L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

When I ran a linear model on my database, I found a clear negative relationship between algae and recruitment

#### Linear Mixed Effects Model

```
module_recruitment <- data$`Module #`
data$Site_long <- as.factor(data$Site_long)
data$Shelter <- factor(data$Shelter, levels = c("Low", "High"), ordered = TRUE) 
# factorize variables

recruitment_lm_A <- lmer(recruits_per_meter_squared ~ combined_cover + Site_long*Shelter + (1|Year/Season), data = data, na.action = "na.fail")
summary(recruitment_lm_A)
```

#### Output

[image]

I want to plot this relationship by calculating the means for both recruitment and algal cover to create a plot with 4 points on it representing means for low and high shelter modules at the two different study sites (Waikiki and Hanauma Bay).  I generated code for this plot by first creating a summary database and then plotting those data as follows:

#### Summary Database and Plot Code

```
std.dev.pop <- function(x) sqrt(sum((x - mean(x))^2)/(length(x)))
std.error.pop <- function(x) (std.dev.pop(x))/(sqrt(length(x)))
#standard error function for error bars

## Summary Database
recruit_algae_data_PR_1_10_summary <- data %>% group_by(Site_long, Shelter) %>% 
  summarise(mean_recruit = mean(recruits_per_meter_squared),
            sd_recruit = std.dev.pop(recruits_per_meter_squared),
            lower_recruit = mean(recruits_per_meter_squared) - 1.96*std.error.pop(recruits_per_meter_squared),
            upper_recruit = mean(recruits_per_meter_squared) + 1.96*std.error.pop(recruits_per_meter_squared),
            mean_algae = mean(combined_cover),
            sd_algae = std.dev.pop(combined_cover),
            lower_algae = mean(combined_cover) - 1.96*std.error.pop(combined_cover),
            upper_algae = mean(combined_cover) + 1.96*std.error.pop(combined_cover),
            sample_size = n())

## Plot Code
recruit_algae_data_PR_1_10_plot <- ggplot(data = recruit_algae_data_PR_1_10_summary, aes(x = mean_algae, y = mean_recruit, fill = interaction(Site_long, Shelter), shape = interaction(Site_long, Shelter))) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = 5)) +
  stat_smooth(method=lm, aes(fill = NULL, shape = NULL)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Shelter)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("dashed", "solid")) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = 'Site x Shelter', values = c(21, 24, 21, 24), labels = c("Hanauma Bay - Low", "Waikiki - Low", "Hanauma Bay - High", "Waikiki - High")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Site x Shelter", values = c(NA, NA, 1, 1), labels = c("Hanauma Bay - Low", "Waikiki - Low", "Hanauma Bay - High", "Waikiki - High")) +
  guides(size = FALSE, linetype = FALSE,  shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 4))) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower_recruit, ymax = upper_recruit), width = 0) + 
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = lower_algae, xmax = upper_algae), height = 0) +
  labs(x = "Mean benthic algal % cover", y = expression(paste("Coral recruitment per m"^"2"))) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), 
        axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1)), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 90), 
        axis.text = element_text(size = 16), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = rel(1.5)), 
        legend.title = element_text(size = rel(1.5)), 
        legend.position = "none", 
        plot.title = element_text(size = 20, hjust = 0.5, vjust = -1.5))
```

#### Plot Output

[image]

Clearly, there is an issue here because the model slope coefficient for algae is negative yet you can clearly see that the trendline for the summary data plot is actually positive.  To check I wasn't plotting the raw data, I ran the raw data and found that the raw data trendline plotted as expected:

```
rawplot <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = combined_cover, y = recruits_per_meter_squared)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = 5)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

#### Rawplot

[image]

I have done both quality control and checked for errors in my code but I still cannot figure out why the trendline in the two above plots are opposite.  Does anyone have an idea of what is going on here and what I need to do to get the first plot (summary data plot) to be representative of the second (raw data plot).  Thanks in advance for any and all input.

Comment: without looking too much into this - how would you expect it to be the same? Your data summary method 1 is peculiar, providing error ranges for both x and y. A linear regression line method 2 is not the same, it gives you the line with the least sum of squares for the residuals.

Comment: Error ranges are needed because both axes represent means.  My confusion is if you take the mean of each Site x Shelter treatment combination and draw a trendline, shouldnt it be the same as the raw data trendline?  After all the means are what are used to calculate slope coefficients to my knowledge

Comment: This seems like a misunderstanding of multiple linear regression methods rather than mixed regressions. You may see the inversion of your expected result when fitting with multiple parameters. This is because you are fitting over the mean-subspace in multiple dimensions. Eg. you are seeing a negative slope in 2 dimensions, but in a higher dimension that the negative part is actually explained by other variables. So given all other variables the remaining effect of "algae" is actually positive. We can only see 3 dimensions (or maybe 4 to 5 if were really good), but that is not all visually.